# Lubuntu 19.10 LXQT How to Extract liblxqt.so files

Tags: linux, libraries

I am trying to see the list of files inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxqt.so.0`.

But any `.so` file I try with `gresource` I get `can't find resource section (null)`

are there any other tools in place of `gresource` or what am I doing wrong?

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ locate liblxqt | grep /x86
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxqt-globalkeys-ui.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxqt-globalkeys-ui.so.0.14.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxqt-globalkeys.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxqt-globalkeys.so.0.14.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxqt.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxqt.so.0.14.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxqt-config/liblxqt-config-cursor.so
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ 

lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ gresource list /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblxqt.so.0
Can't find resource section (null)
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely reason it doesn't work is that liblxqt is a Qt library, whereas the gresource tool is from the Gtk orbit.

The [Qt resource system manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) doesn't mention a dedicated tool to extract this information from a binary.

You could however take a look at GammaRay... it is a bit overkill, but [seems to be able](https://doc.qt.io/GammaRay/gammaray-qresource-browser.html) to do what you want.

Comment: thank you sounds good n clear